# Create a PDF with map imagery and feature data from ArcGIS API for Javascript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to allow the user to zoom to a particular zoom, within their preferred extent, and then send this information to a PDF as well as relevant information from visible features. The end result would be a PDF with map imagery, showing the location at the users zoom level, as well as grabbing data from the visible features and filling in a report-like set of data within the PDF as well.

Is something like this possible or maybe even being done already by anyone?

Comment: Not sure in Javascript but I created a GPTool in Python where user sends the extent and layers info (WebMap JSON from the application) to include in PDF file. I used `arcpy.ExportWebMap_server` to get extract image and `reportlab` to create PDF report.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like what I need. I am still a noob when it comes to Python, I've edited a few models but haven't delved. I've got the book "PYTHON Scripting for ArcGIS" book but haven't had enough time to dig in yet. Looking forward to it... Any chance you could copy and paste or share that code somehow?

Comment: Okay, so how can I help you, do you want script or the ArcGIS custom tool which I made?